# Detect occupation period from electricity consumption TS

Tags: machine-learning, descriptive-statistics, supervised-learning

I have the following Time series which represent electricity consumption throughout the day

[image]

My question is what's the best method to detect the occupation period ? which in this case 6 am to 7 pm.

Comment: How do you define or characterize an "occupation period"?  After all, the data tell us there is above-baseline consumption at least through 10:00 pm.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred approach is to construct/identify a useful model that detects a level shift (intercept change) , possible trend changes and possible 1 period anomalies while incorporating ARIMA structure.  Your plot suggests a level shift in the beginning and a downwards trend at the end. This is referred to as Intervention Detection http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html . Schemes that assume that you should form an ARIMA model and then subsequentally identify intervention points are often inadequate as the identified ARIMA model is flawed by the untreated values. Why don't you post actual data and I will try and demonstrate what you need to do.

Comment: Great here is the data https://files.fm/u/ewfq5avk hope the format suits you

Comment: You cannot possibly do this (in any justifiable way) without additional information, because you are proposing to generalize from a sample of *one* single day.

Comment: in the sample above theres one year period of data

Comment: can you please post this as an excel readable file ...365 rows (representing days ) and 24 columns representing hours where I don;'t have to install any software

Comment: If you have more than 1 year please post all your data .

Comment: why don't you email me the data (dave@autobox.com)